# JSON object gives error while sending JSON request

Tags: java, json, netbeans

From the below JSON, I want to display the Query string. I have done it by using JSON parser.

```
{
    "group By": "name",
    "time Period": {
        "from": "2015-12-29",
        "to": "2016-02-29"
    },
    "query String": "[nation]: \"India\" AND [education]: \"be",
    "geography": "NA",
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 10
}
```

While running, it shows error as

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["query String"] is not a JSONObject.
```

My JSON query is:

```
String request  = rs.getString("Request");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(request);
JSONObject newJSON = jsonObject.getJSONObject("groupBy");
String input = newJSON.toString();
```

Comment: Your code doesn't ask for `query String` at all - although it does ask for `groupBy` as if it were a JSON object, which it's not, and by the wrong name. The code you've given doesn't match the error you've shown. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the "query String" of your json. I got it working with this part of code:

```
String json = "{ \"group By\": \"name\", \"time Period\": { \"from\": \"2015-12-29\", \"to\": \"2016-02-29\" }, \"query String\": \"[nation]: \\\"India\\\" AND [education]: \\\"be\\\"\", \"geography\": \"NA\", \"offset\": 0, \"limit\": 10 }";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
String input = (String) jsonObject.get("query String");
```

The output of `input` is:

```
[nation]: "India" AND [education]: "be"
```